# What is the relationship between keys, indices, primary keys and clustered keys in RDBMS?

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, rdbms

I am pretty confused about these terms in RDBMS:
Keys, and indices: Are they the same concept? For example:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO_TABLE (
    THE_KEY INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
    FOO INTEGER NOT NULL,
    BAR INTEGER NOT NULL,
    QUZ INTEGER UNIQUE,
    CONSTRAINT UNQ_FOO UNIQUE (FOO, BAR)
);
```

In this table, which is a key? Which can be called an index? Is there 'non-primary key' in this table? And how does they improve the efficiency of searching?
Thanks.

Comment: With "*or in SQL*", you mean `Microsoft SQL Server`? SQL is just a query *language*. Btw. Not every DBMS has the concept of a "clustered index".

Comment: I am sorry for my imprecise phrasing. I mean, in any RDBMS with SQL as query language. I will edit my question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: re 'Not every DBMS has the concept of a "clustered index".' Say what! A clustered index is simply the storage of the table on disk, with an associated lookup mechanism. Whether that lookup mechanism is an implied field in the form of a RecordNumber, or an explicit field(s) defined in the system catalog is moot; it remains the clustered index for the table.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Postgres or Oracle do not work that way (unless you use an index organized table in Oracle - which is the same thing as a clustered index in SQL Server). The rows are spread randomly in the "heap" storage. There is no "index" structure available the way it is with a clustered index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key is used to uniquely identify a record.  The primary key is the main way of identifying a record in a given table and should be present in each table of your DB.  A unique key is an additional key.

An index is used to speed up queries.  Usually an index is automatically created for each key because using a key as a search criteria is very common.

In your example you have a one-column primary key called "THE_KEY" and a two-columns unique key composed by columns "FOO" and "BAR".  You should have two indexes too, one for each key.

Answer (score -1):

Copied from my earlier answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350950/multi-column-primary-keys/15565562#15565562) to a different but related question.

1. Confusion arises because the terminology devised by Date, Codd, et al to describe the Conceptual Model (ie entities, attributes,
   relations, keys) has since been co-opted by vendors to describe
   properties of the physical implementation of that model (tables,
   columns, records, indices). It is vital to understanding that the
   two domains be kept separate and identifiable as we discuss the
   issue.
2. First Normal Form states that every relation has a primary key in
   the Conceptual Model. An artificial key that exists solely in the
   Physical Model does not qualify; but note that some so-called
   artifical keys are NOT in the Physical Model, but actually in the
   Conceptual Model. (An example of this is SSN/SIN in the US and
   Canada, as uniqueness cannot be guaranteed in the Conceptual Model
   without it.) More on this below, but to avoid confusion I will
   henceforth refer to a primary key from the Conceptual Model as the
   Natural Key. (Multiple candidates would be candidate Natural Keys.)
3. The Primary Key Constraint in current RDBMS implementations serves
   several purposes. One is to impose a uniqueness constraint on
   physical records to allow update-in-place of all fields not part of
   this (physical) Primary Key constraint; when it is possible for a
   field of a Natural Key to change over time it is thus imperative
   that no such field be part of the Primary Key Constraint in the
   Physical Model.
4. Another use of the Primary Key Constraint is to enable foreign key
   lookups from related tables, which end is most efficiently addressed
   by the narrowest possible Primary Key Constraint. For this purpose
   Natural Keys make poor choices of Primary Key Constraint because
   they are usually too wide (being human reaabale) for optimal index
   size and height.
5. From this I infer a corollary: that the most efficient translation
   to the Physical Model of a Natural Key from the Conceptual Model is
   usually a Uniqueness Constraint combined with a distinct and
   disjoint artificial Primary Key Constraint. Note that in cases (such
   as SSN/SIN) where the Natural Key is required to have an artificial
   component, it is desired to have an additional artificial Primary
   Key Constraint that resides wholly in the Physical Model; this
   because it is necessary to allow for the externally-visible
   artifical number to be changed and/or re-assigned. (How many knew
   that US SSN's are re-used some months after death?)

Comment: First Normal Form has nothing to do with the concept of primary key. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form. The uniqueness of a tuple is defined in the theoretical model by the fact that relations are sets, therefore every element is unique (the whole combination of fields if needed). In practice, this uniqueness is not even mandatory in RDBMS which allow for duplicate records, unless there are constraints of uniqueness.